# Prove that square of number of form $2k+1$ is $8n+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Need show that $\forall k, \exists n \in \mathbb{Z}, (2k+1)^2 =8n+1$.

 $4k^2 + 4k +1 = 4k(k+1) +1$.

Although, $2k+1$ is an odd number, but $k$ can be any integer.
 So, $k+1$ can be an odd or an even number. Hence, not sure of getting the number of the form $8n+1$.

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to say that $(2k + 1)^2 = 8n + 1$ for some integer $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Recursively</strike> By induction : if $n$ is odd then $$\begin{align}n^2  &= (n-2 +2)^2 \\ &= (n-2)^2+ 4(n-2) + 4 \\ &= (n-2) ^2 + 4(n-1)\end{align}$$ And since $n-1$ is even, $4(n-1)$ is a multiple of $8$.

Comment: Please elaborate, as $(n-2)^2$ is also odd, & if $4(n-1)$ is of the form $8k$ for some integer $k$, then need sum, i.e. the other term $(n-2)^2$ too. Here, you state that it is a recursive solution. So, for $n=9$, i.e. odd number of the form $2n'+1$, the sequence is: $9^2$$ = 7^2 + 4(8) = 5^2 + 4(6) + 4(8) = 3^2 + 4(4) + 4(6) + 4(8)$ $ =1^2 + 4(2+4+6+8) = 4.2(1+2+3+4)+1$. But, it is not obvious without working out a case(value for $n$). Is there a way to make the recursion obviously lead to the form $8k+1$ without taking help of an example. Also, not feel it a proof, but seems a new problem.

Comment: Oops, I'm French, and I made a confusion between "Recursively" and "By induction"... :)  So what I meant is : by the induction hypothesis, $(n-2)^2$ is of the form $8k+1$. Is this clearer ?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the inductive approach, but it is still one and the same proof-wise(may be by all other ways too, unless you can point out the difference). Also, I feel that there is upwards-backwards induction in place. In both need help of the base step to show that it has the form $8k+1$ and proceeding upwards, the form is kept. We can show for $n=9$, that for the base case of $n=3$, get $1 +8$, but moving upwards, it is difficult for me (still) to show that each step the same form is kept. Seemingly, need additional logic.

Comment: To elaborate in Euclidean algorithm for finding $\gcd$ need to show at (i) each step that the set of common divisors for dividend, divisor, remainder are the same; and (ii) the base step has 'the' single divisor value as $\gcd$. The missing logic, in your answer, by drawing a parallel is that of step (i) for the Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: Also, the Euclidean algorithm is recursive. If the proof is inductive, or not, I am not clear.

Comment: I'm sorry but I have a hard time understanding your confusion. My answer shows that if $(n-2)^2$ is of the form $8k+1$, then, by adding $4(n-1)$ - that is by adding a multiple of $8$ - you end up with $n^2$. Thus $n^2$ is also of the form $8l+1$. The base step is simple : $1 = 8\times 0 + 1$. Could you clarify what's bothering you ?

Comment: I hope that glue is $n-2$ being an odd number too. So, it is okay. Can state that using the base step, & moving one step up it is shown that the penultimate step's r.h.s. is also of the $8k+1$ form, and so on till the value of $n$ is reached. But, regarding, the difference between recursive or inductive, I am totally confused.

Comment: Yes, thanks for correcting me in that the base case will consider the l.h.s. value of $n$, so the base case is for $n=1$. Am confused why you differentiated between recursive and inductive approaches.

Comment: Both concepts are relatively close (in French, *récurrence* and *récursivité* share the same root). **Induction** means : the base step $n=1$ works, and if the property holds for an odd number $k$, then the property holds for the next odd number $k+2$. Using this, and calling $u(n)$ the square of $n$, we can define $u(n)$ by **recursion** for the odd $n$ : $u_1 = 1$ and $u(n) = u(n-2) + 4(n-1)$. Recursion is a way to define a sequence using its previous terms while induction is a proof technique.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the same. I request your email id, so as to enable discussion on questions related to induction. Otherwise, I will ping you here, or in your future responses to request your response to such questions posted / for creating a chat-room.

Answer (score 2):

$k$ and $k+1$ are consecutive integers, so either $k$ is even or $k+1$ is even. Hence $4k(k+1)$ is divisible by $8$.

Comment: I got stuck when $4k(k+1)$ term had two cases. I feel that further elaboration on your lines is very easy:(i) even $k$ : $4$.even.(odd), (ii) odd $k$: $4k$(even )= 4$.odd.even$. Also, product of even and odd numbers is even, and any even number $k'$ can be expressed as $k' = 2n'$, for some integer $n'$. So, proved.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $(2k+1)^2 = 4k(k+1) +1 = 8\binom{k+1}{2}+1$.